# how to find latest element added or deleted in dynamic array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I am getting an input array in loop which contains numbers in sorted order. on Every iteration the input array will either be added or be deleted with any one number (no duplicates in input array). Example

```
1st iteration: Input Array [3,4,8,19]
2nd iteration: Input Array [3,4,5,8,19]
Output: 5 added
3rd iteration: Input Array [3,4,5,8,19,40]
Output: 40 added
4th iteration: Input Array [3,5,8,19,40]
Output: 4 deleted
5th iteration: Input Array [1,3,5,8,19,40]
Output: 1 added
```

**Note:** I have a solution where I can take a map or different array and copy the input array in new array then from next iteration onward I'm going to iterate input array and compare the input array's elements with new array, the one not present in new array is the one added; and the one present in new array but not present in input array is the one deleted. I am looking for a better approach with most optimized logic in terms of space and time.

Comment: You add to the input array yourself or someone else adds it? Is your only job to detect change as to whether something was added or deleted?

Comment: Would you be able to share us a minimum reproducible code you are on?

Comment: @vivek_23 : a reactjs package is doing this on checkbox click. On every check box click I am getting the input array with checked Ids in sorted format. I have just optimized the problem in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: React? Is this JavaScript? You've tagged Java

Comment: @Ronald: minimum you can take 5. max it is infinite. Its an application's onAction event giving me this array with sorted Id's

Comment: @Joni: anything will work. Java, javascript . I am more focused on logic, language I'll take care. Just seeking the best algo

Comment: @ShreyaBhatnagar how about making the variable private and putting getter and setter for the array and use them for determining that?

Comment: Is the change by at most one element?

Comment: @Joni : its only and only by one element. Every time only one element will be either added or deleted as of now.

Comment: @ShreyaBhatnagar How large the array can get?

Comment: @vivek_23: The answer is infinite. But I'll restrict this array to particular size depending upon application's performance as I cant maintain infinite array on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is one of the simplest ways:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first[] = { 3, 4, 8, 19 };
        int second[] = { 3, 4, 5, 8, 19 };
        int diff = Arrays.stream(second).sum() - Arrays.stream(first).sum();
        System.out.println(Math.abs(diff) + (diff > 0 ? " added." : diff < 0 ? " deleted." : ""));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5 added.
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] testArrs = { 
                { 3, 4, 8, 19 }, 
                { 3, 4, 5, 8, 19 }, 
                { 3, 4, 5, 8, 19, 40 }, 
                { 3, 5, 8, 19, 40 },
                { 1, 3, 5, 8, 19, 40 } };
        int i, diff = 0, lastSum = Arrays.stream(testArrs[0]).sum(), currentSum;

        for (i = 1; i < testArrs.length; i++) {
            currentSum = Arrays.stream(testArrs[i]).sum();
            diff = currentSum - lastSum;
            System.out.println(Math.abs(diff) + (diff > 0 ? " added." : diff < 0 ? " deleted." : ""));
            lastSum = currentSum;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5 added.
40 added.
4 deleted.
1 added.
```

Comment: for more optimization we can do this without using second array ? I mean on every iteration when I am getting input array, I can store its summation in a variable and subtract it with a further iteration's input array's summation. if final answer is positive - added, else - deleted (same as you have provided in the code).

Comment: @ShreyaBhatnagar - Good point! I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is always sorted and the input only changes in one place, then if you have access to both the old and the new array at each iteration, an efficient algorithm could search for the first different elememt between the arrays in `O(log n)` time with binary search. If mid points to different elements, look in the left half; otherwise, in the right.

Comment: Yes this is best solution if I am bound to take second/ new array. Still looking for solution where I dont have to maintain second array. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: on every iteration I am getting an input array with the sorted values from which I have to find the latest added/deleted value. That means at a given point of time I have only one array. What I am looking for is solution without using any additional array. am I clear now ?

Comment: @ShreyaBhatnagar no. Without having any information stored about a thing, `A`, it would be logically impossible to know about the difference between `A` and another thing, `B`.

Comment: Yes I'll store some info in each iteration for given input array but dont want a data structure for it, variables should be enough.